# Problem in running cen/xfs client application as windows service

Tags: windows-services, cen-xfs

I'm developing a cen/xfs client application in c++ which will register for the events and receive it. I installed the application (.exe file) as a windows service and the system is rebooting after few minutes once i started the service, but when i execute the .exe file directly it works properly. Anyone know why?

Comment: Did you try check "Allow service to interact with desltop" in service properties Log On page?

Comment: Thanks Alex.D.Alexeev. System rebooting not happened after tried what you said. Application registered for the events, but events not received. Any idea regarding that?

Comment: I think, that using xfs call in service is not a good idea, because of different access rights of service and user. Service also may be started when desktop not created and there are no any windows is ready. If you want to deal with xfs from service you may write your own proxy to interact between service and desktop application. Any xfs related message you may process with desktop application and than transfer to your service